# angular-tree-control remove overall padding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I want to remove the padding on the left:

[image]

and have it like so:

[image]

But when I try to apply the following :

```
[treecontrol] li {
    padding: 0;
}
```

It sets the padding of the children to 0px too:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the greater than symbol to express immediate children. Try the following code:

```
treecontrol > ul > li { padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options in [documentation](https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control#usage), which will allow you to specify classes on different kind of elements in the tree:

> `injectClasses` : allows to inject additional CSS classes into the tree DOM
>       `ul` : inject classes into the ul elements
>       `li` : inject classes into the li elements
>       `liSelected` : inject classes into the li 
>       `elements` only when the node is selected
>       `iExpanded` : inject classes into the 'i' element for the expanded nodes
>       `iCollapsed` : inject classes into the 'i' element for the collapsed nodes
>       `iLeaf` : inject classes into the 'i' element for leaf nodes
>       `label` : inhject classes into the div element around the label
>       `labelSelected` : inject classes into the div element around the label only when the node is selected

And you can use your class on `treecontrol` directive element to combine it with inner classes in `css` rules:

```
<treecontrol class="tree-classic" ... ></treecontrol>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. John's answer allowed me to do what I wanted.

Comment: OK if so, but keep in mind that it is a bad practice to use inheritance in `css`. Especially inheritance of tags. It's much better to write css rules for classes only. For details read [this](http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/).

Comment: I tried adding class to li (a2), and use that class to set padding to 0, but that did not work... It sets all the files as shown in the last pic. Can you suggest a css? (I tried: .tree-classic .a2 { padding: 0})